# How to rewrite this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have got this code for my website, which I built myself and works fine. The thing is, that I want the JavaScript code 'cleaner'. I read that JavaScript was all about not-rewriting code. The problem is that I don't really know how to restructure the dropDownOne through dropDownSeven functions. 
Each of the functions corresponds to a particular button, which on click then shows the corresponding information block by applying the class 'show' on it, which only got one property: Display: block;

So to wrap it up: how do I get to rework the code, so that I only need say, one function for all the buttons to click on. If a particular button is clicked, that buttons content should show, and not that from the others.

-No jQuery-

HTML:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="dropDownFour()" class="projectbuttons">
               PSD to Bussiness Site (01-2017)
        </button>
        <div id="dropdownfour" class="dropdown-content">
        <!--Content-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function dropDownOne() {
 document.getElementById("dropdownone").classList.toggle("show");
}

function dropDownTwo() {
 document.getElementById("dropdowntwo").classList.toggle("show");
}

function dropDownThree() {
 document.getElementById("dropdownthree").classList.toggle("show");
}

function dropDownFour() {
 document.getElementById("dropdownfour").classList.toggle("show");
}

function dropDownFive() {
 document.getElementById("dropdownfive").classList.toggle("show");
}

function dropDownSix() {
 document.getElementById("dropdownsix").classList.toggle("show");
}

function dropDownSeven() {
 document.getElementById("dropdownseven").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
 if (!event.target.matches('.aboutmebuttons, .projectbuttons, 
                             #mailopenbutton, [name="name"],
                             [name="message"], ' + '[name="email"],
                             [name="submitmail"], [name="reset"],
                             #dropdownseven, #mailform')
     ) {
         var dropDowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        for (var i = 0; i < dropDowns.length; i++) {
           var openDropDown = dropDowns[i];
           if (openDropDown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropDown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
     }
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: Put id's in an array, loop it, keep a common function and pass the values to that function in the loop.

Comment: This should be in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function dropDown(id){
    document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}
```

And then you could use it like that

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="dropDown('dropdownfour')" class="projectbuttons">PSD to Bussiness Site (01-2017)</button>
    <div id="dropdownfour" class="dropdown-content">
    <!--Content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function dropdown(dropdown){
  document.getElementById(dropdown).classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Then use this HTML:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="dropdown('dropdownfour')" class="projectbuttons">
            PSD to Bussiness Site (01-2017)
        </button>
        <div id="dropdownfour" class="dropdown-content">
        <!--Content-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use the **this** and  ***event*** keywords:

Change this html line:

```
 <button onclick="dropDownFour()" class="projectbuttons">
```

to:

```
<button onclick="dropDown(this, event)" class="projectbuttons">PSD to Bussiness Site (01-2017)</button>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

> In an in–line event handler
>
> When code is called from an in–line on-event handler, its this is set to the DOM element on which the listener is placed:

And the final function is:

```
function dropDown(ele, evt) {
  ele.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

The snippet:

```js
function dropDown(ele, evt) {
    ele.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.show {
    display:  none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="dropDown(this, event)" class="projectbuttons">PSD to Bussiness Site (01-2017)</button>
<div id="dropdownfour" class="dropdown-content">
    <!--Content-->
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
</div>
```

Another short form is based on:

- [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded): when document is ready
- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll): select all button with class under div with class
- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener): create the [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) event handler [for each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) element

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
   document.querySelectorAll('div.dropdown button.projectbuttons').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
        ele.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            ele.classList.toggle("show");
        })
    });
});
```

```css
.show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="projectbuttons">PSD to Bussiness Site (01-2017)</button>
  <div id="dropdownfour" class="dropdown-content">
      <!--Content-->
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="projectbuttons">PSD to Bussiness Site (01-2017)</button>
    <div id="dropdownfour" class="dropdown-content">
        <!--Content-->
        bbbbbb
    </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
    <button  class="projectbuttons">PSD to Bussiness Site (01-2017)</button>
    <div id="dropdownfour" class="dropdown-content">
        <!--Content-->
        ccccc
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that way also

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="dropDown(this)" class="projectbuttons">
        1 button
    </button>
    <div id="dropdownone" class="dropdown-content">
    <!--Content--> 1 content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="dropDown(this)" class="projectbuttons">
         2 button
    </button>
    <div id="dropdowntwo" class="dropdown-content">
    <!--Content--> 2 content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="dropDown(this)" class="projectbuttons">
           3 button
    </button>
    <div id="dropdownthree" class="dropdown-content">
    <!--Content--> 3 content
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function dropDown(element){
     element.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[0].classList.toggle("show") ;
}
```

Thanks,